# Fatal Error :1:1: 文件提前结束。 Exception in thread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler"

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I checked out some files from SVN , and I want to use these files to generate a java project. My codes to generate the java project as below:

```
 package uiautomatortestplatform.svn;  
 public class SvnProjectImport{


    private IProject project;
    private static ArrayList<String> filesList=new ArrayList<String>();
    private String projectName;
    private String projectPath;

    public SvnProjectImport(String projectName,String projectPath){
        this.projectName=projectName;
        this.projectPath=projectPath;//该路径在miuitestmarmot目录下
    }


    public void createMarmotProject() throws FileNotFoundException {

        IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
        project = root.getProject(projectName);
        IPath svnProjectPath=new Path(projectPath);

        //setting the project attribute
        NullProgressMonitor monitor=new NullProgressMonitor();
        if(!project.exists()){
            IProjectDescription description=ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().newProjectDescription(project.getName());
            description.setLocation(svnProjectPath);
            String[] oldNatureIds=description.getNatureIds();
            String[] newNatureIds=new String[oldNatureIds.length+1];
            System.arraycopy(oldNatureIds, 0, newNatureIds, 0, oldNatureIds.length);
            newNatureIds[oldNatureIds.length]=JavaCore.NATURE_ID;
            description.setNatureIds(newNatureIds);         
            try{
                project.create(description,monitor);
                project.open(IResource.BACKGROUND_REFRESH, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor,1000));
                project.setDescription(description, monitor);
            }catch(CoreException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            try{
                IProjectDescription description=project.getDescription();
                description.setLocation(svnProjectPath);
                String[] oldNatureIds=description.getNatureIds();
                String[] newNatureIds = new String[oldNatureIds.length+1];
                System.arraycopy(oldNatureIds, 0, newNatureIds, 0, oldNatureIds.length);
                newNatureIds[oldNatureIds.length]=JavaCore.NATURE_ID;// 定义工程为java工程
                description.setNatureIds(newNatureIds);
                project.open(IResource.BACKGROUND_REFRESH, new SubProgressMonitor(new NullProgressMonitor(), 1000));
                project.setDescription(description, new NullProgressMonitor());
            }catch(CoreException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       

        //change to java project
        IJavaProject javaProject=JavaCore.create(project);

        //get the JRE
                IClasspathEntry[] jreClasspaths=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PreferenceConstants.getDefaultJRELibrary();

                IClasspathEntry[] oldClasspathEntries=null;
                try{
                    oldClasspathEntries=javaProject.getRawClasspath();
                }catch(JavaModelException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Set<IClasspathEntry> newClasspathEntries=new HashSet<IClasspathEntry>();
                newClasspathEntries.addAll(Arrays.asList(jreClasspaths));
                newClasspathEntries.addAll(Arrays.asList(oldClasspathEntries));
                try{
                    javaProject.setRawClasspath(newClasspathEntries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[newClasspathEntries.size()]), monitor);
                }catch(JavaModelException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        //create the folder
        IFolder binFolder=javaProject.getProject().getFolder("bin");
        try{
            if(!binFolder.exists()){
                binFolder.create(true, true,monitor);               
            }
            javaProject.setOutputLocation(binFolder.getFullPath(),monitor);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        IFolder srcFolder=javaProject.getProject().getFolder("src");
        try{
            if(!srcFolder.exists()){
                srcFolder.create(true, true, monitor);
            }
            //javaProject.setOutputLocation(srcFolder.getFullPath(), monitor);
        }catch(CoreException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //create the files under the src folder 
        String srcPathStr=projectPath+File.separator+"src";
        filesList=fileTraversal(srcPathStr);
        for(String s:filesList){
            IPath eachFilePath=new Path(s);
            javaProject.getProject().getFile(eachFilePath);
        }

        IFolder libsFolder=javaProject.getProject().getFolder("libs");
        try{
            if(!libsFolder.exists()){
                libsFolder.create(true, true, monitor);
            }
        }catch(CoreException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        //src classpath entry writing to .classpath file
        IClasspathEntry classpathEntry=JavaCore.newSourceEntry(srcFolder.getFullPath());
        newClasspathEntries.add(classpathEntry);
        IClasspathEntry removeEntry=JavaCore.newSourceEntry(new Path("/"+project.getName()));
        if(newClasspathEntries.contains(removeEntry)){
            newClasspathEntries.remove(removeEntry);
        }
        try{
            javaProject.setRawClasspath(newClasspathEntries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[newClasspathEntries.size()]), monitor);
        }catch(JavaModelException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String miuiTestMarmotPath=projectPath;
        String androidJarPath=miuiTestMarmotPath+File.separator+"libs"+File.separator+"android.jar";
        String uiautomatorJarPath=miuiTestMarmotPath+File.separator+"libs"+File.separator+"uiautomator.jar";
        String miuiMarmotJarPath=miuiTestMarmotPath+File.separator+"libs"+File.separator+"marmot.jar";
        InputStream uais=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(uiautomatorJarPath));
        IFile uaFile=javaProject.getProject().getFile("uiautomator.jar");
        InputStream is=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(androidJarPath));
        IFile file=javaProject.getProject().getFile("android.jar");
        InputStream miuiAutois=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(miuiMarmotJarPath));
        IFile miuiAutoFile=javaProject.getProject().getFile("marmot.jar");

        try {
            file.create(is, false, null);
            IPath path=file.getFullPath();
            newClasspathEntries.add(JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(path, null, null));
            uaFile.create(uais, false, null);
            IPath uaPath=uaFile.getFullPath();
            newClasspathEntries.add(JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(uaPath, null, null));
            IPath miuiAutoPath=miuiAutoFile.getFullPath();
            miuiAutoFile.create(miuiAutois, false, null);
            newClasspathEntries.add(JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(miuiAutoPath, null, null));
            javaProject.setRawClasspath(newClasspathEntries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[newClasspathEntries.size()]), monitor);
        } catch (ResourceException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            MessageDialog.openInformation(new Shell(), "Project existed!", "miuiTestMarmot has readly existed!");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       try{
            javaProject.getProject().refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);//refresh the project
        }catch(CoreException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> fileTraversal(String path){
        File srcPath=new File(path);
        File[] files=srcPath.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return null;
        for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
            if(files[i].isDirectory()){
                fileTraversal(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }else{
                filesList.add(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return filesList;
    }
}
```

It generated the java project successfully, however when I double clicked the .java files under the src folder to edit the files , I got the [Fatal Error] :1:1: 文件提前结束。
Exception in thread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" error and "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" Did my memory leak? and how to fix?

Comment: Just a note on memory leaks: In your snippet I don't see any place where you close the `InputStream uais`, `InputStream is` and `InputStream miuiAutois` (if you don't close those you have resource leaks, but is most likely not related to your problem)

Comment: It seems not the problem of Permgen space

Comment: Yes, however it might cause problems later if you don't close them since they are leaking.

Comment: I add"-XX:PermSize=512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M"  in eclipse.ini, then made it~thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just run your eclipse with more PermGenSpace.

Check out [the eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse?) on how to set it.

Comment: I have changed the size of PermGen Space, but it has no effects

Comment: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms512m -Xmx1024m  this error also shows when I increate Permgen Space.